# java hexadecimal to int conversion - have to remove 0X ?

Tags: java, input, integer, hex

I have a file with many hex numbers (for eg -  0X3B4  ). Im trying to parse this file as assign these numbers to integers, but dont seem to get Integer.parseInt to work.

```
   int testint = Integer.parseInt("3B4",16);  <- WORKS

   int testint = Integer.parseInt("0X3B4",16);
```

gives error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x3b4"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
```

What is the right way to assign the value 0XB4  to an int ?

Do I **have** to get rid of the 0X - its not unusual to represent hex nos this way...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
int hex = Integer.decode("0x3b4");
```

You are right that parseInt and parseLong will not accept 0x or 0X

Comment: Thanks. Also this doesn't work in java 1.4.1 , I can use it in a higher version though.

Comment: @Nik I suspect 1.4.1 is ten years old now. ;)